# macOS, segue kind popover not allowed from toolbar

Tags: swift, xcode

I would like to ask why is possible to create a segue of kind `popover` or `sheet` by dragging from a button to a `NSWindow` or `NSView` by you cannot from a toolbar item?

From a toolbar only allows kind: show, modal and custom

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not really sure why this isn't possible through dragging in Interface Builder, you can still present a popover manually by using the target/action mechanism. Your toolbar button will call an action like `presentFooPopover(:)`, which in turn will call `NSViewController`'s `presentViewController(_ viewController: NSViewController, asPopoverRelativeTo positioningRect: NSRect, of positioningView: NSView, preferredEdge: NSRectEdge, behavior: NSPopover.Behavior)` to present the popover's target view controller from some position in some view.

The presenting view controller (on which you call `presentViewController...`) doesn't have to own the view you use for positioning. Note also the `positioningRect` must be in the `positioningView`'s coordinate system, so the view's `bounds` is usually used.

Putting all that together, you can pass the button (`sender` in your action) as the positioning view and use its bounds. The view controller responsible for presenting the popover could be your window controller or your window's content view controller (or really anything that won't go away while the popover is still presented, which would also dismiss the popover).